# Choosing when to execute in Python

Tags: python, debugging, exec, eval, pygame

I'm a student writing a Python script to achieve the following:

Given a .py file(that includes drawing logic from pygame), show the code as it is being executed, along with a frame that displays the drawings. I am writing this as a tool for a professor to more easily teach algorithms, by being able to demonstrate the code and its result simultaneously.

The major problem that I am running into is being able to stop at each line of code, and wait for a user response to continue. This feature is very similar to a "step into" from any debugger.

One method I've looked into is using the exec() and eval() functions when executing the code from the provided source file. In this investigation, I have found the general opinion that exec and eval are very confusing and often unsafe (even though I will be controlling the input). With this method, I would be sequentially stepping through the source, while looking for branches or decision-making logic that may influence what is to be executed.

Is there a better method to employ than this?

Comment: Recycle an existing debugger. `exec` works on complete modules (or at least complete blocks), you'd have to emualte branching, looping, scopes, etc. - so much you'd end up writing half a Python interpreter.

Comment: You want a debugger, look at debugger. See how stdlib's `pdb` is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you wrap the python debugger itself into your program, and have it execute within it - and use its hooks to graphically track the current line being executed?

I've also seen someone embed an ironPython interpreter into their program - and you can probably track the current code being executed within it and feed it data into a GUI.

http://writeonly.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/embedding-a-python-shell-in-a-python-script/